# How to get empty field with autonumeric.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, autonumeric.js

I want to be able when I am focused on the field, and I have minimum an maximum limits (1-31), I want to be able to delete all the numbers, but it wont me let it to do that. If I enter 17, I can delete 7 and thats it. I want to be able to delete both digits and to re-enter some others.
Currently my setup of autonomueric is:

Version: 1.9.45

```
    $("#field").autoNumeric({
        vMin: '1',
        vMax: '31',
        aPad: false,
        aSep: ''
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following code

```
 $(".testInput").autoNumeric('init', {
           vMax: '31',
           vMin: '-1',
       aPad: false,
        aSep: ''
        });
```